# How to generate two versions of image on carrierwave after applying crop method? Rails 5 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have an avatar_uploader.rb that uses carrierwave to create multiple versions of the uploaded avatar and also has a crop method.

```
  version :thumb do
    process :crop
    resize_to_fill(100, 100)
  end

  version :miniature do
    resize_to_fill(25, 25)
  end

  version :large do
    resize_to_limit(600, 600)
  end

  def crop
    if model.crop_x.present?
      resize_to_limit(600, 600)
      manipulate! do |img|
        x = model.crop_x.to_i
        y = model.crop_y.to_i
        w = model.crop_w.to_i
        h = model.crop_h.to_i
        img.crop!(x, y, w, h)
      end
    end
  end
```

The problem is that I need two versions after the crop method is applied. I want a miniature version that is just a smaller version of the thumb, which is a cropped version of the original file.

The crop method requires that the user crop the image and needs to be called through a view to get the x, y, w, h attributes. So it should only be done once. It wouldn't make sense for the user to crop the image twice for two versions.

Now, it would be convenient if I could define the version miniature to apply the resize_to_fill on the thumb version but I don't know what the syntax for that would be.

I want to write this:-

```
  version :miniature do
    thumb.resize_to_fill(25, 25)
  end
```

But that just gives an error and says thumb is undefined.

Is there a way to achieve this?

**Update:-**

I don't think I explained this problem clearly.

The miniature version gets regenerated but the problem is that the crop doesn't alter the original file. It just creates the thumb version. When the miniature version is applied, it miniaturizes the original file, and not the thumb version. I want the same crop as the thumb version but in miniature dimensions. So ideally I want to apply the miniature version on the thumb version. I don't know how to achieve this. Hope this is clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `recreate_versions!` on your image after the crop to do this. So you could do:

```
model.image.recreate_versions!(:miniature)
```

UPDATE:

You seem to have a crop on `:thumb`, but for what you want, I would suggest a custom crop of the original, then recreate the versions after that. [This Railscast from Ryan Bates](http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images-revised?view=asciicast) explains it well.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Not sure if I explained the problem properly, please see the update in the question.